# Find records with Minimum length data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, datalength

I have a table `#tempTest` with data like this:

```
ID  Name
1   A
2   AB
3   ABC
4   ABCD
5   ABCDE
6   ABCDEF
7   X
8   QRWXYZ
```

Now I need the shortest name from the table.

I've tried this way:

```
SELECT TOP 1(name) Smallest  FROM #tempTest
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY LEN(name)
```

And that represents:

```
Smallest
A
```

But what I need is:

```
ID  Name
1   A
7   X
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES (name) Smallest  FROM #tempTest
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY LEN(name)
```

Comment: might be worth adding some information about the `WITH TIES` syntax as it's not that common. MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx. *WITH TIES Used when you want to return two or more rows that tie for last place in the limited results set. Must be used with the ORDER BY clause.*

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, name FROM #tempTest
WHERE LEN(name) = (SELECT MIN(LEN(name)) FROM #tempTest)
```